# How to add multiple image urls into postgres database using fastAPI?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

Using the fastAPI multiple uploads function, i am trying to upload images to my server and save the urls as a list to my postgres database.
Here is the code i am using to upload the image:

```
@router.post('/addProductFD', status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=ShowProduct)
async def create(
    name: str = Form(...),
    price: float = Form(...),
    description: str = Form(...),
    files: List[UploadFile] = File(...),
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
):
    for file in files:
        try:
            FILEPATH = "./static/product_images/"
            pimage_name = FILEPATH + imghex(file.filename)
            contents = await file.read()
            with open(pimage_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(contents)
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file(s)"}
        finally:
            await file.close()
    file_urls = "localhost:8000" + pimage_name[1:]

    new_item = Product(
        name=name,
        price=price,
        description=description,
        imgs_url=file_urls,
    )

    db.add(new_item)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_item)
    {"filenames": [file.filename for file in files]}
    return new_item
```

When i run this code, it uploads the images and adds the url of just the first image to my database. Please how do i make this code to add the image urls to my database as a list.
Here is an example of what i want to do:
[image]

Below is the schemas.ShowProduct:

```
class ShowProduct(ProductBase):
    name: str
    description: str
    img: str

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

Below is my postgresDB models.product:

```
class Product(Base):
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    owner = relationship("Vendor", back_populates="product")
    img = Column(String)
```

So i want to recieve a list of the imageurls and add it to the **img** database column:

Please help!

Comment: 1) I am not seeing `price` in you model, yet I see `price=price,` in `new_item`. 2) `file_urls` is being constructed outside the `for file in files` loop so it looks to be catching just the last file. 3) Show an example of how you want the URL's represented in the column.

Comment: Hello @AdrianKlaver it was a mistake on my end due to trying to simplify my models before i post it. Sorry about that.  I posted an image of what i want to achieve. The answers posted below worked for me. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to alter your db model:

```py
class Product(Base):
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    owner = relationship("Vendor", back_populates="product")
    imgs_url = Column(ARRAY(String))
```

Note: do not forget to generate and apply migration.

then simply pass `imgs_url` as a `list` to `Product` initializer:

```py
new_item = Product(
        name=name,
        price=price,
        description=description,
        imgs_url=["url1", "url2"],
    )
```

Finally, you can alter your model factory:

```py
class ShowProduct(ProductBase):
    name: str
    description: str
    imgs_url: list[str]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

I think you should rethink your design and take imho better approach, with table relationships. So you would create two tables: `products` (as already defined) and `images` (new one) which will be connected via foreign key:

```py
class Product(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    owner = relationship("Vendor", back_populates="product")
    images = relationship("Image", back_populates="product")
```

```py
class Image(Base):
    url = Column(String, nullable=False)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product.id"))
    product = relationship("Product", back_populates="images")
```

Comment: Hello @needtobe. I get the urls from the uploaded images. In my case, what do i add for the ```["url1", "url2"]``` since its a userinput?

Comment: I think i agree with you on the second approach will give it a try now too.

Comment: Finally got your anser to work. I had to combine your answer with that of @Charlie V due to the need to create a ```filelist[ ]``` . Thank you.

Comment: Yes, just pass the list there.

Comment: Hello @bc291 Why is the **ForeignKey** for **product_id** ```images.id``` ? Shouldn't it be ```product.id``` ? Mistake?

Comment: Yes, my bad, so as follows: `product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product.id"))`.

Comment: I am trying to implement the second approach like you said. But i am running into problems. Will create the question now and send you the link. Thanks.

Comment: Is this the correct approach? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72591246/12986987

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the urls in the for-loop.

first make an empty array to store the file urls, then in the for loop append to it. Then finally use join to concatenate the strings with commas to  give you a string with comma separated items

```
fileList = []
for file in files:
        try:
            FILEPATH = "./static/product_images/"
            pimage_name = FILEPATH + imghex(file.filename)
            contents = await file.read()
            with open(pimage_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(contents)
        except Exception:
            return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file(s)"}
        finally:
            await file.close()
        fileList.append("localhost:8000" + pimage_name[1:])

    file_urls = ",".join(fileList)
```

Comment: Wow. Its working now. I had to combine your answer with that of @needtobe due to the need to change my dattabase column from **String** to **Array** . Thanks so